# vb6 - how to find largest element index in control array?

Tags: vb6, control-array

I am dynamically loading and unloading an array of command buttons on a form.

I can do this:

```
    Dim UnloadIndex As Integer
    For UnloadIndex = 1 To 20
        Unload frmMain.cmdAction(UnloadIndex)
    Next
```

But I don't always have 20 elements. Is there a way to loop through each one until it reaches the end?

I know I can use a global variable and track the value but I'm trying to avoid this.

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`UBound()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which returns the highest available subscript for the indicated dimension of
an array.

```
Dim UnloadIndex As Integer 
For UnloadIndex = LBound(frmMain.cmdAction) To UBound(frmMain.cmdAction)
    Unload frmMain.cmdAction(UnloadIndex) 
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I also needed to keep the very first button. So I decided to go from 1 to UBound... Thanks and +1 for your quick response.

Comment: +1 although you have linked to the VB.Net docs. Here is the VB6 topic for `Ubound` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263396(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 5):

If they're not sequential, you could also do:

```
Dim Control as CommandButton
For Each Control in frmMain.cmdAction
  If Control.Index > 0 Then
    Unload Control
  End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to the often over-looked fact that there can be gaps. Also possible to start at an arbitrary lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim UnloadIndex As Integer 
For UnloadIndex = LBound(frmMain.cmdAction.LBound) To UBound(frmMain.cmdAction.UBound)
    Unload frmMain.cmdAction(UnloadIndex) 
Next
```

I found that the accepted answer way  gives a compile error

> expected array

Using dot notation instead worked for me.

Comment: you are right on both counts! the accepted answer is a compilation error. and your method works perfectly.